# When should we create a Custom TypeHandler in mybatis?

Tags: mybatis, ibatis

The below line is from the doc : [https://mybatis.org/mybatis-3/configuration.html#:~:text=Whenever%20MyBatis%20sets%20a%20parameter,and%20Time%20API](https://mybatis.org/mybatis-3/configuration.html#:%7E:text=Whenever%20MyBatis%20sets%20a%20parameter,and%20Time%20API))%20by%20default.

Whenever MyBatis sets a parameter on a PreparedStatement or retrieves a value from a ResultSet, a TypeHandler is used to retrieve the value in a means appropriate to the Java type.

Also, we can override the type handlers or create our own to deal with unsupported or non-standard types.

*So, one such scenario I have seen is for Json Type where we need custom TypeHandler since Json type is not supported by mybatis. Is my understanding correct ?*

*Also, I want to know few other types which isnot supported by mybatis (just curious), I searched on net but couldnot find anything relavent.*

Comment: Yes, type handler for JSON seems to be popular. There is no built-in type handler for JSON because there is no JSON type in JDBC API. Another example is [UUID](https://github.com/mybatis/mybatis-3/issues/1609) for the same reason.

Comment: You typically use TypHandlers for any type that is not supported by your database: e.g. `boolean` does not exist in Oracle or DB2. I've also seen it for any kind of on-the-fly conversion of data; e.g. adapting the time zone of a timestamp between the database and the app that runs in multple time zones.

Comment: @TheImpaler.. Json datatype is supported by postgres database but still ibatis/mybatis requires a TypeHandler for Json. So, I think we use TypeHandler If its not supported by ibatis/mybatis and not the database.